# What feature selection method is ideal for a large dimensional data frame after the result of one hot encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, feature-selection, preprocessing

I am trying to solve a sports related multi class classification problem in Python, I aim to train a custom neural network and also a SVM. I have performed prior data cleaning and encoded my data using one-hot encoding for the non-numerical values. However due to one hot encoding the data frame is quite large now. So I wanted to perform feature selection, however after doing some research there is a wide a range of feature selection methods. What specific method should I go for?

The data contains numerical input features and categorical target variables (Home Win, Away Win or Draw) which I have encoded using label encoder.
The overall shape of the data including features and the target column is 2280 rows and 128 columns.

Comment: Look at boruta or lasso

Comment: gradient boosting methods easily handle categorical features without encoding.

Comment: Is there any reason to actually perform feature selection apart from performance improvements? as in is there any issue with just using all features in a dataframe